# `id` prints only numbers for non-root users

Tags: users, group

When I use the `id` command, it does not resolve to user- and group names (for `admin` it works):

**User `backup` and `admin`:**

`backup`:

```
# id
uid=1005 gid=100 groups=100
```

`admin`:

```
# id
uid=0(admin) gid=0(administrators) groups=0(administrators),100(everyone)
```

`/etc/passwd`:

```
# cat /etc/passwd 
admin:x:0:0:administrator:/share/homes/admin:/bin/sh
guest:x:65534:65534:guest:/share/homes/guest:/bin/sh
httpdusr:x:99:0:Apache httpd user:/share/homes/httpdusr:/bin/sh
backup:x:1005:100:Linux User,,,:/share/homes/backup:/bin/sh
sshd:x:501:501:Linux User,,,:/tmp:/bin/false
```

**`etc/passwd` permissions look like this:**

```
# ls -l passwd 
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        13 Mar 12 23:27 passwd -> config/passwd

# ls -l config/passwd
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       519 Mar  6 09:55 config/passwd

# ls -l config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        21 Apr  3 21:47 config -> /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/

# ls -ld /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.conf*
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       274 Apr  3 21:47 /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.conf
drw-r--r--   31 admin    administ      4096 Apr 11 10:50 /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/

# ls -l /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       519 Mar  6 09:55 /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd
```

**`ls` does also fail to resolve names and groups:**

`backup`:

```
# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 0        0               28 Feb 26 14:20 @Recycle -> /share/homes/@Recycle/backup
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     100           4096 Apr 10 21:40 test
```

`admin`:

```
# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        28 Feb 26 14:20 @Recycle -> /share/homes/@Recycle/backup/
drwxr-xr-x    2 backup   everyone      4096 Apr 10 21:40 test/
```

**nsswitch.conf looks like this:**

```
# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf 

passwd:     compat winbind
shadow:     compat
group:      compat winbind

hosts:      files dns wins 

bootparams: files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files 
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   files

publickey:  files

automount:  files
aliases:    files
```

What could be the reason for that?

System is a QNAP, firmware 4.2.4, I believe this is based on busybox 1.x.

**EDIT: it seems I cannot read `passwd` file:**

```
# su backup
# cat /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd
cat: can't open '/mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd': Permission denied
```

But permissions seem to be ok..

```
# su admin
# ls -l /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       519 Mar  6 09:55 /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/passwd
```

Comment: Exactly what Linux (?) are you running?

Comment: Does `ls` resolve the names?

Comment: Show your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Comment: `/etc/passwd` has correct permissions (root:root, 644) ?

Comment: I think so, see edited question.

Comment: What are the permissions of /etc/config?

Comment: Try to read the `/etc/passwd` file from a normal-user account (backup ?). If you fail than check step-by-step all the directories permissions as probably you don't have an access to one of them.

Comment: @kerner1000 One of the intermediate directories in the path to `passwd` may be read protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions on the `/mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config` directory are wrong. Here is the correct set of permissions for the directories leading to `/etc/passwd`, taken from a QNAP we have here:

```
drwxr-xr-x   18 admin    administ      1024 Mar 17 16:28 /
drwxr-xr-x   24 admin    administ      2048 Mar 18 03:00 /etc/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 admin    administ        21 Mar 17 16:25 /etc/config -> /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/
-rw-r--r--    1 admin    administ       227 Feb 21  2016 /etc/config/passwd

drwxr-xr-x   30 admin    administ      4096 Apr 11 04:00 /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config/
```

Comparing to yours, your `/mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config` is missing its read and execute permissions. Fix with this command

```
chmod a=rx,u+w /mnt/HDA_ROOT/.config    # or chmod 755 ...
```

It would be worth keeping an eye on this after your next reboot and raising a ticket with QNAP Technical Support if the permissions revert to the broken settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot! No idea how the permissions got messed up, I will keep an eye on that!